# Can't install cabal by stack

Tags: cabal, haskell-stack

when I want to install cabal by stack, an error occured:

=================
~$ stack install cabal

Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were
encountered:

In the dependencies for cabal-0.0.0.0:
    youProbablyWantCapitalCabal must match <0 && >1, but the stack configuration
                                has no specified version (no package with that
                                name found, perhaps there is a typo in a
                                package's build-depends or an omission from the
                                stack.yaml packages list?)
needed since cabal is a build target.

Some different approaches to resolving this:

- Consider trying 'stack solver', which uses the cabal-install solver to
  attempt to find some working build configuration. This can be convenient
  when dealing with many complicated constraint errors, but results may be
  unpredictable.

Plan construction failed.

=================
Then I try to use `stack solver` to solve it following the hint. But it still failed:

=================
~$ stack solver
Using configuration file: stack.yaml
Using cabal packages:
- cabel/

No changes needed to stack.yaml

=================
It seems that I should configured the stack.yaml. But What should I Do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message says, you actually want `stack install Cabal` (note the capitalization!)

Comment: OK, your solution works perfectly. Thank you very much